# how do I import an array with mixed floats and non-numeric strings, with strings converted to zeros

Tags: python, arrays, string, mixed

I have an array similar to `[1.124, 5.152, 6.235, NaN, 5.124, Infinity]`. And I would like to import it as `[1.124, 5.152, 6.235, 0, 5.124, 0]`. How do I do this?

Comment: Is `Infinity` a predefined variable?

Comment: I'm saving a set of ImageJ measurements as a .txt file and importing with np.loadtxt. Because of adjustments to X/Y scale I end up with NaN or Infinity in 2 of 34 columns-I don't really need these columns anyway so I just want to replace those values with zeros. I supposed I could import around those columns but then I would have to rewrite a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter based on NaN's and Inf:

```
print([float(ele) if ele not in {"NaN","Infinity"} else 0 for ele in arr])
```

If you are using numpy.

```
arr = np.genfromtxt("a.txt", dtype=float,delimiter=",")
print(arr)
arr[~np.isfinite(arr)] = 0
print(arr)
[ 1.124  5.152  6.235    nan  5.124    inf]
[ 1.124  5.152  6.235  0.     5.124  0.
```